# mod_rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, blogs

Hey all, how can I reduce this:

```
www.example.com/index.php?page=viewblog&category=awesome
```

down to this:

```
www.example.com/blog/awesome
```

The above lists all of the blog posts in that category, but I also want scope for adding the title of the post on the end of it as well, like this:

```
www.example.com/index.php?page=viewblog&category=awesome&post=why-trees-are-green
```

And this needs to shorten down to:

```
www.example.com/blog/awesome/why-trees-are-green
```

Any ideas, anyone? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Wait, are you trying to map the "nice" URLs to a PHP page? Or redirect visitors that use the old index.php URLs to the new, "nice" ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule blog/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=viewblog&category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule blog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=viewblog&category=$1&post=$2 [L]
```

The condition makes sure the requested URL is not an actual file, which you want to serve (css, images, etc.)

Then, one rule per level, the first one will rewrite 
`http://yourserver.com/blog/whatever` to
`http://yourserver.com/index.php?page=viewblog&category=whatever`

The second one will rewrite `http://yourserver.com/blog/whatever/whenever` to
`http://yourserver.com/index.php?page=viewblog&category=whatever&post=whenever`

If you need more levels, add more rules accordingly.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the comprehensive and quick answer :)

Comment: it seems to work without RewriteCond. i didn't use it, and works fine.

what RewriteCond do?

Comment: @Syom: The first line in the answer explains it. You usually want to return the files if they exist instead of rewriting those requests. Example: Suppose you have an image on server/blog/blogimage.png if you didn't have the condition there (which ensures that the requested resource does not exist) then your request would be rewritten to server/index.php?page=viewblog&category=blogimage.png instead of actually returning the image.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/([^./]+)$ index.php?page=view$1&category=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/([^./]+)/([^./]+)$ index.php?page=view$1&category=$2&post=$3 [L]
```